# Reusing PCollection from output of a Transform in another Transform which is later stage of pipeline

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

In java or any other Programming we can save state of a variable and refer the variable value later as needed. This seems to be not possible with Apache beam, can someone confirm? If it is possible please point me to some samples or documentation.

I am trying to solve below which needs context of my previous transform output.

I am new to Apache Beam so finding it hard to understand how to solve the above.

Approach#1:

```java
PCollection config = p.apply(ReadDBConfigFn(options.getPath()));
PCollection<Record> records = config.apply(FetchRecordsFn());
PCollection<Users> users = config.apply(FetchUsersFn());
```

// Now Process using both 'records' and 'users', **How can this be done with beam?**

Approach#2:

```java
PCollection config = p.apply(ReadDBConfigFn(options.getPath()));
PCollection<Record> records = config.apply(FetchRecordsFn()).apply(FetchUsersAndProcessRecordsFn());
```

// Above line 'FetchUsersAndProcessRecordsFn' needs 'config' so it can fetch Users but **there is seems to be no possible way?**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use elements from the two collections `records` and `users` in a processing step?  There are two commonly used patterns in Beam to accomplish this:

If you are looking to join the two collections, you probably want to use a [CoGroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey) to group related records and users together for processing.

If one of the collections (records or users) is "small" and the entire set needs to be available during processing, you might want to send it as a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) to your processing step.

It isn't clear what might be in the `PCollection config` in your example, so I may have misinterpreted...  Does this meet your use case?